# How to deal with a mix of I(1) and I(2) variables?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, vector-autoregression, unit-root, ardl

I have one dependent variable which becomes stationary after the first difference I(1).

There are 4 independent variables, out of which 2 become stationary after the first difference and the other two after the second difference. So, two I(1) and two I(2) variables.

I can not use ARDL or VAR because of the stationary constraints. So how should i proceed?

I know by doing the second difference i can make all the variables stationary and then proceed with VAR, but is it okay to 2nd diff?

Also, can i use log diff for this purpose.

Or maybe i could drop one of the I(2) variables and proceed with VAR even if one of the independent variables is non-stationary.

For info, size of the data is around 250.

I'm a beginner here. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do not difference an I(d) variable more than d times. This will lead to overdifferencing and its negative consequences. ARDL may accommodate variables with different orders of integration; see Dave Giles' blog posts on that. Also, variables with an order of integration above 1 are rare; make sure that what looks like I(2) to you is not actually I(1). Also, check out existing threads; we have had similar questions asked and answered before. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I%281%29%22+%22I%282%29%22) are some, though the search needs to be refined further.

Comment: @RichardHardy you were right. I also did Phillips-Perron Testing on my variable. It was actually I(1). I was doing ADF test earlier. It might be because PP test is sensitive to structural breaks.